# Gravar dados no arquivo dando UP na última postagem

Tags: php, html

Pessoal tenho esse código, ele grava os dados captados do formulário em uma página HTML, porem se eu envio um post e depois envio outro, o post mais recente fica sempre em baixo, mas eu quero que ele fique em cima (como acontece em um blog).

Como resolve isso?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
<?php 

    $file = 'abc.html'; // Open the file to get existing content 
    $current = file_get_contents($file); // Append a new person to the file 
    $current .= $_POST ["top"]; 
    $current .= '<br>'; 
    $current .= $_POST ["texto"]; 
    $current .= '<br>'; 
    $current .= '<img alt="" src="images/'; 
    $current .= $_FILES ['imagem'][name]; $current .= '">'; 
    $current .= '<br>'; 
    $current .= $_POST ["rodape"]; 
    $current .= '<br><br>'; // Write the contents back to the file     
    file_put_contents($file, $current); 

?>
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="envia.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   




<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent;" alink="#000099" link="#000099" vlink="#990099">
<video autoplay="" loop="" poster="URL-FUNDO" class="bg_video"> <source src="video/bg.webm" type="video/webm"> <source src="video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source> </source></video>
<div class="cabecalho">
<a id='inicio'></a>


<table
 style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 100px; text-align: center;"><p>
        

</p>

<p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Top:</span></big><br />
    <textarea required="required" name="top" id="top" cols="40" rows="7" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px"></textarea>
</p>

    <p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Texto:</span></big><br />
        <input type="text" required="required" size="40" name="texto" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px">
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" multiple>
        
    </p>
<p>

<p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: bold;">Rodapé:</span></big><br />
    <textarea required="required" name="rodape" id="rodape" cols="40" rows="7" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px"></textarea>
</p>


<p>
    
     <button type="image" name="gravar" value="Gravar" id="gravar"><img style="width: 130px; height: auto;" src="../img/enviar.png"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso esta acontecendo porque você esta colocando o [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) no inicio.

```
<?php 

    $file = 'abc.html'; // Open the file to get existing content 

    $current = "";

    // adicionar os dados do arquivo antes
    //$current .= file_get_contents($file); // Append a new person to the file 

    $current .= $_POST ["top"]; 
    $current .= '<br>'; 
    $current .= $_POST ["texto"]; 
    $current .= '<br>'; 
    $current .= '<img alt="" src="images/'; 
    $current .= $_FILES ['imagem'][name]; $current .= '">'; 
    $current .= '<br>'; 
    $current .= $_POST ["rodape"]; 
    $current .= '<br><br>'; // Write the contents back to the file 

    // Adicionar os dados do arquivo depois
    $current .= file_get_contents($file);  

    file_put_contents($file, $current); // Guarda os dados no arquivo 

?>
```